# java.nio.file.Files.delete(path) method throws java.nio.file.FileSystemException, when trying to remove file after creating and using it

Tags: java, spring-boot

My scenario is the folowing, I'm getting some data from db, writing it to a file, then giving that file by inputStrem to the client response.
Here is the code doing this:

```
public void getErrorsFile(UUID jobId, Pageable pageable, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<ValidationErrorsDTO> failedList = getValidationErrors(jobId, pageable);
    String fileName = "failedRows.txt";
    PrintWriter writer;
    Path path = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
        for (ValidationErrorsDTO dto : failedList) {
            String line = dto.getLineNumber() + ": " + dto.getValidationMessage() + "\n";
            writer.println(line);
        }
        writer.flush();
        path = Paths.get(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try (InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(path)) {
        writeStreamToResponse(response, inputStream, fileName);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        Files.delete(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void writeStreamToResponse(HttpServletResponse response, InputStream inputStream, String fileName) throws IOException {
    response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    response.setContentType("txt/plain");
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

And when running this code, all the phases go well, except the one, which removes the file at the end.And I get this exception

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: failedRows.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

The speps I did for solving the issue:

1. I did put the process of removing file in another thread, thinking that it's a concurrency issue.
2. No other process is holding this file somehow I think.
3. I did try another way of removing the file, used java.io.file.delete
   method.
4. I did put the process of removing file in finally block.
   Nothing helps.

Will appreciate any useful suggestion.

Comment: Looks like you're not closing the Writer

Comment: writer.flush(); doesn't do that?

Comment: Yes, that was definitely the issue, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should have open the writer instance as `try-with-resources` similar to opening the input stream:

```java
try (writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8")) {
        
    for (ValidationErrorsDTO dto : failedList) {
        String line = dto.getLineNumber() + ": " + dto.getValidationMessage() + "\n";
        writer.println(line);
    }
    writer.flush();
    path = Paths.get(fileName);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```